# How to save the date the user presses a button in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I want the code to run once a day, but the way I want to accomplish this is by disabling the button after it is clicked and then reenabling when it has been more than 24 hours.

Would the code below be correct to just save the date the user pressed the button?

```
if distance < radius{
    Total_Points += 10
    pointsLabel.text = "Total Points: \(Total_Points)"

    getPointsOutlet.isEnabled = false

    let clickdate = UserDefaults.standard

    if var timeList = clickdate.object(forKey: "timeList") as? [Date]{
        timeList.append(Date())
        clickdate.set(timeList, forKey: "timeList")
    } else {
        clickdate.set([Date()], forKey: "timeList")
    }
    clickdate.synchronize()
}


let PointsDefault = UserDefaults.standard
PointsDefault.setValue(Total_Points, forKey: "Total Points")
```

Comment: You don't need to create a new variable every time you call `UserDefaults.standard`, you can either use it as is (e.g. `UserDefaults.standard.setValue(...)` or define it a single time and reuse it (e.g. `let defaults = UserDefaults.standard` and later `defaults.setValue(...)`

Comment: Thank you, I will change that, but what about saving the date the user presses the button?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve in this way when you tapped on button save the date value using `Userdefaults` and then inside your ViewDidAppear, ViewDidload and `UIApplicationWillEnterForeground` notification method put the check to get dateValue from user defaults and then take the difference of current date and last stored date and accordingly enabled your button.

```
lazy var userDefaults: UserDefaults = {
        return UserDefaults.standard
    }()
func ViewDidLoad() {
  UserDefaults.set(Date(), forKey:"date")
  userDefaults.synchronize()
}

func someMethodWhereYouWantToGetValue() {
 guard let value = userDefaults.object(forKey: "date") as? Date else 
{return}
 print(value)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how how do I save the date? I attempted it in my code above but I am not sure if it is correct

Comment: Try this:-   let def = UserDefaults.standard
  def.set(NSDate(), forKey: "date")
  print(def.object(forKey: "date"))

Comment: It worked, but I am getting a warning for the print line saying "expression implicitly coerced from 'Any?' to Any' "

Comment: That was just an example to see the value. You do not need to use the print statement.

Comment: Oh okay, now the second part of your answer is where I do not know how to code, wouldn't I only have to code in the viewDidLoad to check the date value from user defaults ?

Comment: Here you go     if let dateValue = def.object(forKey: "date") {
   print(dateValue)
  }

Comment: And inside you can compare time difference like let time = Date().timeIntervalSince(dateValue)

Comment: Now would I have to code this in `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear`, and `UIApplicationWillEnterForeground`?

Comment: That code is required to enable your button if time difference is more than 24 hours right?

Comment: Yes and for the Date().timeIntervalSince(dateValue)  would I code that int he viewDidLoad?

Comment: yes thats right and if this helps then please accept the answer

Comment: I am getting an error in the viewDidLoad saying "cannot convert value of type 'Any?' to expected argument type 'Date'"

Comment: Follow this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45374975/how-to-read-a-saved-date-in-viewdidload-in-swift/45375338#45375338

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
let clickdate = UserDefaults.standard

if var timeList = clickdate.object(forKey: "timeList") as? [Date]{
    timeList.append(Date())
    clickdate.set(timeList, forKey: "timeList")
} else {
    clickdate.set([Date()], forKey: "timeList")
}
clickdate.synchronize()
```

Is fine for adding a date to an array of saved dates. You could pull that out into a separate function:

```
func addDateToDefaults(date: Date? = nil) {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    if date = nil {
        date = Date()
    }

    if var timeList = defaults.object(forKey: "timeList") as? [Date]{
        timeList.append(date)
        defaults.set(timeList, forKey: "timeList")
    } else {
        defaults.set([date!], forKey: "timeList")
    }
}
```

Then you could call that from a button action:

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    addDateToDefaults()
    //The rest of your button action code goes here
}
```

With the function `addDateToDefaults()` above, you can pass in a specific date, or leave off the date parameter and it will append the current date to your array of dates.